# How get position of socket stream while reading

Tags: c++, boost, asio

Is it possible to find offset or position of stream socket while you use function of boost like **async_read_some**?

For example i use next code in **handle_read** when program reads big amount of json text in socket session and i want to know exactly position of stream when i read data like so:

```
socket.async_read_some(
    boost::asio::buffer(data, max_length),
    boost::bind(&Session::handle_read, this, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)
 );
 //socket.get_offset() or socket.get_position()
```

In documentation i cant find any appropriate solution for it.

The maximum buffer size is 65536 bytes, but socket gets the json text even bigger.

I cant properly append chunks of buffer in the right position because async do it in the some sort of shuffle result but i need to do it in the right way.

Comment: What do you mean by position of stream? May be you want to get newly received data actual size?

Comment: i dont want to know actual size of read data. when you sending big size of string through socket and read it in async way you dont know the exactly position of read stream data. when you want to append data by using async read you dont get in the right file, you'll get shuffle text of data. Because async read do it in some sort of random processing.

Comment: If I understood you right, checking `boost::asio::error::eof` can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to get the actual size of received data, its value can be obtained inside the callback function (`Session::handle_read`) in the second parameter.

To read big streams you can check `boost::asio::error::eof` error code inside the handler

```
    if (!err)
    {
        // Continue reading remaining data until EOF.
    }
    else if (err != boost::asio::error::eof)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << err << "\n";
    }
```